# Query systemindex of remote PC for its crawl scope

Tags: windows, search, indexing

This question regards **Windows Search (WDS v4)**

I am trying to use `ISearchCrawlScopeManager::IncludedInCrawlScope` to determine whether a remote (local network) folder (both PCs running WDS4) is included in the index of the remote PC. I am getting the remote catalog using

```
ISearchManager::GetCatalog("remotePC.SystemIndex")
```

`IncludedInCrawlScope` call succeeds but the answer is always "not in the index" even for folders that are in the remote `SystemIndex`.

Is this querying something that is prevented from access permissions?

If I do a search query (i.e try to find files) on the remote machine, the query works. So why am I not able to check whether a shared folder is indexed or not?